# Passing updates to GUI from outside of callback class

Tags: python, gtk, python-2.7

This is a bit of a conceptual question.

I am learning Python. I built a GUI and a callback class to handle events. I'd like to keep the callback class just handle events, and call methods in another .py file where all the heavy work is actually done.

However, I have a progress bar in my GUI and a detail window that displays all the work the process is doing.

If I have all of the heavy-work methods within the callback class, I can easily update the progress bar and the detail window, then call:

```
while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()
```

To update the GUI before doing more work.

But how do I do that if my heavy-working methods, which also update the GUI, are placed in their own .py file / class of its own?

Here is my example:

This is in the method I want to place outside of my callback class:

```
#Some work before here

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directoryname, True):
    for fileName in files:
        totalFileCount = totalFileCount + 1

self.textBuffer.insert(self.textBuffer.get_end_iter(),
                       "Number of files and subdirs found for "
                       + directoryname + ": "
                       + str(totalFileCount) + "\n")
self.textViewDetail.scroll_to_iter(self.textBuffer.get_end_iter(),
                                   0,
                                   False,
                                   0,
                                   0)
self.walkProgress = progressbar.progressBar(0, totalFileCount)

while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()

#some more work after here
```

I think, this is a disconnect in my understanding on how classes are suppose to work, and my reading of the documentation is not getting me much farther.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this technique:

http://unpythonic.blogspot.com/2007/08/using-threads-in-pygtk.html